# R Plotly -- How to add borders to histogram bars

Tags: r, plotly

everyone!

Sorry for the painfully easy question, but I'm stuck.

I am trying to add borders to these histogram bars and am trying to set their thickness with `span`. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>%
  plot_ly( x = ~cut, showlegend = FALSE ) %>%
  add_histogram(hoverinfo = "x+y", 
                hoverlabel = list(font = list(color = "red"), bgcolor = "yellow")) %>%
  dplyr::group_by( cut ) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  add_text(
    text = ~scales::comma(n), y = ~n,
    textposition = "top middle",
    cliponaxis = FALSE,
    hoverinfo = "none",
  )
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation (https://plotly.com/r/bar-charts/), specifically the fourth, fifth, and sixth charts down the page, it looks like you can use the keyword argument `line` like so `line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5)` which would set the color and width of the border of the histogram bars.

Comment: Thank you! However, I cannot get that to work in my code. Where should what you mentioned be placed in the code? Thanks again!

Comment: I figured it out. It should go in another list() function under the marker option within add_histogram(). Thanks again!